# How to enable logging (most verbose) for vsftpd?

Tags: linux, logs, vsftpd

I'm trying to enable logging for vsftpd so I can see uploads, downloads, and, more specifically, deletion of files; however, I haven't even been able to get normal logging working with a fresh install of centos 6.

Setup:

```
[root@sftp01 vsftpd]# cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

[root@sftp01 vsftpd]# netstat -naplt
    Active Internet connections (servers and established)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      367/vsftpd          
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      507/sshd            
    tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      507/sshd   

[root@sftp01 ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                          |  12 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * epel: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: mirror.eboundhost.com
base                                                                                                                   | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                                        | 4.7 MB     00:01     
epel                                                                                                                   | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                        | 5.9 MB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                                      |  29 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                     | 3.1 MB     00:00     
repo id                                         repo name                                                                               status
base                                            CentOS-6 - Base                                                                          6,706
epel                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                          12,380
extras                                          CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                           45
updates                                         CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                         565
```

Default config:

```
[root@sftp01 vsftpd]# grep -v ^# /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf 
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Connecting via sftp for a system user works fine.  I've tried many different combinations for the logging options (dual_log_enable, vsftpd_log_file, xferlog_file and others listed in the man page) and creating the log files manually with various permissions.

How do I get vsftpd to log?

---

updated:

```
[root@sftp01 vsftpd]# cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

xferlog_std_format=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
log_ftp_protocol=YES

[root@sftp01 vsftpd]# /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
Shutting down vsftpd:                                      [  OK  ]
Starting vsftpd for vsftpd:                                [  OK  ]
```

After logging in with sftp, uploading a file, deleting that file, and logging off (no ftp-related info):

```
[root@sftp01 vsftpd]# tail -f /var/log/*
==> /var/log/secure <==
Aug 29 13:48:22 sftp01 sshd[1253]: Accepted password for test from 192.168.10.10 port 35825 ssh2
Aug 29 13:48:22 sftp01 sshd[1253]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user test by (uid=0)
Aug 29 13:48:22 sftp01 sshd[1255]: subsystem request for sftp
Aug 29 13:48:31 sftp01 sshd[1253]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user test
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need to add a location for log file

```
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

For verbose logging you will need to add

```
log_ftp_protocol=YES
```

And comment

```
xferlog_std_format=YES
```

Comment: You should also use `service vsftpd restart` not just `vsftpd restart`

Answer (score 1):

Connections from sFTP have nothing to do with VSFTPD but run over SSHD. 
sFTP connections will be unaffected by these changes, only FTP connections.

I got it working with Centos 7.5 by changing the following:

> log_ftp_protocol=YES 
>  xferlog_enable=YES 
>   xferlog_std_format=NO

Answer (score 1):

In the logs we can see that connection is made to SFTP server. If you in reality want to configure SFTP and not FTP, that server can be configured in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, snip from that file:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

FTP, FTPS and SFTP are not the same thing. SFTP uses port 22 by default.
FTP and FTPS use port 21 by default (and possibly other ports).

With **CentOS 8**, I got **vsftpd** logging working by configuring below in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`:

```
# This is by default YES
xferlog_enable=YES

# This was changed from default YES to NO.
# This was actually the setting preventing from logging properly.
xferlog_std_format=NO

# Changed logfile from default as this makes more sense to me
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

# Enable verbose logging
log_ftp_protocol=YES
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're really just adding another OS that [user2827958's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486803/117549) works for; is that correct?

Comment: More important point than the OS was that the topic starter is actually probably using SFTP and not FTP. I was super confused about FTP and SFTP when I started configuring them the first time. I hope that the snip from the `ssh_config` will help somebody else to realize that they could just use SFTP which running quite often by default, instead of intensive research of FTP.

Secondly I was wondering maybe half an hour why my CentOS 8 is not logging with FTP, so hopefully this helps the next person. I would have added just a comment to previous answer if I could comment the posts.

Comment: This is actually the only answer that addresses the crux of the problem;  vsftpd != sftp